# TOC section symbol/numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

So I've come to the following problems while writing something in LaTeX, first, I want to have the numbering of a section of the output to be just a number not depending of the chapter.  (not like 1.1, 1.2 etc)

i.e.

> Chapter 1
>
> 1. Section 1
> 2. Section 2
>
> Chapter 2
>
> 1. Section 1 in chapter 2
> 2. Section 2 in chapter 2

etc, but, on the TOC I want it to look like

> Chapter 1
>
> §1. Section 1
> §2. Section 2
>
> Chapter 2
>
> §1. Section 1 in chapter 2
>
> §2. Section 2 in chapter 2

To have the first one I used

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart \arabic{section}}
```

with

```
\documentclass[leqno, 12pt, twoside,letterpaper]{book}
```

But I can't get the TOC with the symbol §, any help would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html)? It is important to know which documentclass you are using.

Comment: How do you want to reference to sections in the different chapters? Might be confusing for the reader.

Comment: @Johannes_B The documentclass is \documentclass[leqno, 12pt, twoside,letterpaper]{book} I'll try to write an MWE later.

Comment: See packages `titlesec` and `titletoc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the number preceeded by the symbol `§` in the TOC, it suffices to to load the package `tocloft` and issue the command:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\S}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt,twoside,letterpaper]{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\S}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Section 1 in chapter 2}
\section{Section 2 in chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Note that I've used

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

instead of yours

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart \arabic{section}}
```

Comment: So this half helped me but I should have written the question differently, please can you see the edit?

Comment: Now sections numbering is totally independent of chapter, but  I wanted to have sections in the following form 1 to 10 in the first chapter, sections 1 to 7 in the second chapter, etc, right now with your solution im getting section 1 to 10 in the first chapter, and sections 11 to 17 in the second chapter.

Comment: @Aram In this case `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` should do.

Comment: @Aram You're welcome. I've changed the answer accordingly.